# Force WordPress Role Post To Custom Post Type Only

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to force a user roles posts to go to a certain custom post type?
My Administrators, Editors, and Authors go to the main post feed. And I want a role I created "Members" to go to a separate "Members" custom post type. Anybody know a way?

Comment: Is your intention to save it as a certain post type? Or is it that you intend to use a certain template associated with a post type for viewing?

Comment: I would like these to save as a certain post type.